# Cannot Receive App Intent Type Nearby Notification - Beacons

Tags: android, android-intent, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

I registered a beacon (simulated by an app on an Android device and is of the type Eddystone-UID) and tried to set up nearby notifications from the Google Beacon Platform dashboard.

When I created a notification of the type "App Intent", it was not received on a device when it was close to the one acting as a beacon. However, if I set up a nearby notification of the type "Web URL", it is displayed on all the device within the range of this beacon.

When setting up the notification of type App Intent, I provide the following details:
1. Intent scheme (same as the scheme in the code below)
2. Package name of the app - same as what's in the app's manifest file
Left the Intent path field blank as it is not mandatory.

This is the intent filter in the app's manifest:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="app" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried looking at several blogs and videos but I'm unable to figure out the problem. Can someone please point out my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with whis

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <!-- both categories below are required -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:host="host"
        android:pathPrefix="/path"
        android:scheme="yourscheme"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: If you have resolved the problem can you post it as an answer?